# Wait async grunt task to finish

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, gruntjs

I received a grunt setup and one of the new tasks should execute (grunt.task.run) already existing task. The task to execute is asynchronous, and the new task should wait until the async task has finished.

What is the preferred way to do this?

Comment: I don't know anything about grunt, but it sounds like web workers might be up to the job. You can give a task its own thread, and provide a callback function for when it's done. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

grunt already got this covered, you should declare your task as an async one, and use the done() func in your task to tell grunt that it is done, look at [this repo](https://github.com/robdodson/async-grunt-tasks/blob/master/tasks/grunt-read-write-local.js) and [this article](https://robdodson.me/posts/asynchronous-grunt-tasks/), that have been very helpfull to me when I first had to deal with async tasks.

without a glimpse at your gruntfile, this is all i could say, but fell free to update your post with a link to the grunfile :)

Comment: hey @gorhgorh, the link to the article isn't working. Do you know of other good source with examples of async grunt tasks? I can't make mine work... thank you