# "Close" callback for spawn() function doesn't work in a grunt plugin

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, gruntjs, spawn

I'm creating a grunt plugin what makes an extensive use of the `grunt.util.spawn`function (http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.util#grunt.util.spawn). The basic skeleton for my plugin is as follows:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {

    var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

    var createCommit = function (text) {
        var commit = grunt.util.spawn({
                    cmd: "git",
                    args: ["commit","-a","-m", text]
        }, function() {
                    console.log("FINISH! FINISH! FINISH!");
        });
    };

    grunt.registerMultiTask("myplugin", "Plugin to commit awesome things", function () {
        createCommit("0.2.0");
    });
};
```

Nevertheless, when I'm trying to execute this grunk task, the `console.log("FINISH! FINISH! FINISH!");` is never executed by mi callback...Someone could help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution in this question ([Wait async grunt task to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897469/wait-async-grunt-task-to-finish)). The key to solve this is the use of the function `this.async` inside of the registration. A possible solution could be:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {

    var spawn = require("child_process").spawn,
        donePromise;

    var createCommit = function (text) {
        var i = 0;
    var commit = grunt.util.spawn({
            cmd: "git",
            args: ["commit","-a","-m", text]
        }, function() {
            callback();
            donePromise();
        });
    };


   grunt.registerMultiTask("myplugin", "Plugin to commit awesome things", function () {
        donePromise = this.async();
        createCommit("0.3.0");
    });
};
```